# Solve the system of equations.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

*There was a mistake in the previous question but it is now fixed:*
$\log_{10}\dfrac{1}{3}(y + 2) \to \log_{\frac{1}{3}}(y + 2)$

> Solve the system of equations for $z\ge0$: $\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
> {{{(3 - x)}^{2003}} = y + 2}\\
> {{{\log }_3}\dfrac{1}{{2z - y}} + \log_{\frac{1}{3}}(y + 2) = {{\log }_{\frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}}}\sqrt {9 + 4y} }\\
> {\log_{2}({x^2} + {z^2}) = 2 + {{\log }_2}x}
> \end{array}} \right.$

The conditions are: $\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x > 0\\
-2< y < 2z\\
z\ge0
\end{array} \right.$

**My try:**

Since $2+\log_2 x=\log_2 4x$, therefore $\log_2 x^2+z^2=\log_2 4x$, which means: $x^2+z^2=4x$

We have: $\log_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\sqrt{9+4y}=\log_{3^{\frac{-1}{2}}}\sqrt{9+4y}=-2\log_3 \sqrt{9+4y}=\log_3 (\sqrt{9+4y})^{-2}=\log_3 \dfrac{1}{9+4y}$,

and: $\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(y + 2)=-\log_3(y+2)=\log_3\dfrac{1}{y+2}$

Therefore, $\log_3 \dfrac{1}{2z-y}+\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(y+2)=\log_3 \dfrac{1}{9+4y}$
is equivalent to: $\log_3 \dfrac{1}{2z-y}+\log_{3}\dfrac{1}{y+2}=\log_3 \dfrac{1}{9+4y}$

This is the same as: $y+2=\dfrac{9+4y}{2z-y}$

Now, the system becomes: $\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{(3 - x)^{2003}} = y + 2\\
y+2=\dfrac{9+4y}{2z-y}\\
{x^2} + {z^2} = 4x
\end{array} \right. \text{for:}$ $\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x > 0\\
-2< y < 2z\\
z\ge0
\end{array} \right.$

Notice that $y>-2 \Rightarrow y+2>0\Rightarrow(3-x)^{2003}>0 \Rightarrow x<3$

Combining with the conditions gives: $x>0\Rightarrow3>x>0$

*By testing, I found that $(x, y, z)=(2, -1, 2)$ is the only solution, so I wanted find it by assuming $x, y, z$ are integers (I'm not sure if this is rigorous) then prove that it is the only solution.*

Assume $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$, as $0<x<3\Rightarrow x \in \{1; 2\}$

For $x=1\Rightarrow z^2=3$ (eliminate because $z \in \mathbb{Z}$)

For $x=2\Rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{l}
z = 2\\
z =  - 2 \text{ (Eliminate because }z\ge0)
\end{array} \right. \Rightarrow y=-1$

For $3>x>2 \Leftrightarrow (3-x)^{2003}<1 \Rightarrow y+2<1 \Leftrightarrow y<-1$, combining with the conditions gives $\Rightarrow -1>y>-2$

From $y+2=\dfrac{9+4y}{2z-y}\Rightarrow y=\pm \sqrt{z^2 - 2 z} + z - 3$

$-1>y>-2\Rightarrow -1> \pm \sqrt{z^2 - 2 z} + z - 3 >-2$ (no solutions) so $3>x>2$ doesn't satisfy.

**Now, the only thing I have to do is to prove $2>x>0$ does not satisfy, but I have no idea how, so I'd like some help. Thanks!**

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to believe the system even has a solution? And if so, do you expect it to be an analytical one?

Comment: This is from a problem book so I'm quite sure that it does have some workaround.

Comment: I suppose there is misprint in second equation.

Comment: I think so, too. Because it's $\log \dfrac{1}{3}(y+2)$ in the book and I'm not sure if it is actually $\log \dfrac{1}{3}(y+2)$ or $\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(y+2)$

Comment: @Snek: If there's a possible error or ambiguity in the question, *say so in the body of your post*. Comments are easily-overlooked and may be hidden. ... As for the ambiguity: Perhaps a photo of the page from your problem book would help resolve it. ... Cheers!

Comment: $\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(y+2)$ changes everything. Then one can find solution by limiting possible values $x$, $y$, $z$.

Comment: The $\log_3 \frac{1}{2z-y}$ term means the implicit domain has $2z-y>0$, not just $2z-y \neq 0$.